# BroadcastReceiver not triggered on boot - programmatically

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, boot

I am trying to start my app if user wishes so on boot. I have checkbox that un/register broadcast receiver. If i declare receiver in manifest my app always starts on boot which is unwanted behaviour. I tried also `getApplicationcontext().registerReceiver` without a luck. Am I missing something?

```
    final BroadcastReceiver startMyActivityAtBootReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Log.i("LockState", "broadcast receiver called started");
            if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                Intent activityIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                activityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(activityIntent);
            }
        }
    };

    if (switch4.isChecked()){
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).registerReceiver(startMyActivityAtBootReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"));
        Log.i("LockState", "broadcastreceiver registered");
    }
    else {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).unregisterReceiver(startMyActivityAtBootReceiver);
        Log.i("LockState", "broadcastreceiver unregistered");
    }

    switch4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            SharedPref.write(Constants.LAUNCH_AT_START, isChecked);
            Log.i("LockState", "launch app at start: " + isChecked);

            if (isChecked) {
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).registerReceiver(startMyActivityAtBootReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"));
                Log.i("LockState", "broadcastreceiver registered");
            } else {
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).unregisterReceiver(startMyActivityAtBootReceiver);
                Log.i("LockState", "broadcastreceiver unregistered");
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be declared in the manifest. You are going about this the wrong way. 
Rather than allowing the user to enable/disable the broadcast receiver for boot, you should handle that option within the receiver itself. Either launch the activity or not, based on the saved user preference value from the checkbox.

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Handle user preference
        if (!isUserPreferenceEnabled()) return;

        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent activityIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            activityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(activityIntent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for clarification! I was confused because the app was in "recent apps" after start but it was actually broadcastreceiver. The *return* part did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

`LocalBroadcastManager` send broadcasts of Intents to local objects within your process, Boot receiver will work over sending global broadcasts.

So we should register the broadcast in AndroidManifest.xml and when you get callback to your Receiver you can check the logic and you can do the action against it.

Example:

```
switch4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            SharedPref.write(Constants.LAUNCH_AT_START, isChecked);
            Log.i("LockState", "launch app at start: " + isChecked);
        }
    });
```

And create a broadcast receiver in a separate class and register in AndroidManifest.xml.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application>
<receiver 
    android:name=".MyBootReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
</application>
```

MyBootReceiver.java:

```
public class MyBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (Check your prefernce) {
                Intent activityIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                activityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(activityIntent);
          }
    }
}
```